# Copy a file from one directory to another while incrementing the filename in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a script that copies a file from one directory to another indefinitely (until cancelled) as a test.  I am trying to write a bash script that takes `file.xml`, copies it to a directory, but increments the filename each time, i.e. `file1.xml`, `file2.xml`, etc.  I've been coming up short thus far with the solutions I've found on SE.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are you testing with that, the page cache...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#! /bin/bash

source_path='/path/to/file.xml'
dest_dir_path='/path/to/dest'

i=1
while true; do
    cp "$source_path" "${/path/to/dest}/file${i}.xml"
    ((i++))
done
```

Comment: Appreciate it.  That is way better than the nightmare I tried.